Ideomatic Rust to storing/freeing externally allocated memory as a ref
An external C library allocates/frees memory via FFI. My rust code is a thin wrapper layer called by C, and allows other Rust developers to write safe Rust code without dealing with FFI from C. My layer needs to hold a reference to C-allocated object and do the Drop when requested by C code to cleanup. What would be the idiomatic way to store a reference to that struct and later free it in this case?
P.S. I am writing an FFI layer to allow safe Rust plugins to Varnish (large C program).  Varnish calls my wrapper layer, which needs to restore context on each callback from some *void pointers before passing them to user Rust code. Sometimes the callback is to clean up resources - so I must restore context, perform drop on user's T, followed by a C-call to free on the FFI C struct that held a pointer to T.
// Code generated by bindgen, from a C header file
#[repr(C)]
pub struct c_object {
    // Here I store a pointer to T - a Rust-allocated user obj
    pub user_obj: *mut ::std::ffi::c_void,
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn allocate_obj() -> *const c_object;
    pub fn free_obj(obj: *mut *const c_object);  // double-ref to set my ptr to NULL
}


// Safe Rust wrapper I need to design
// lifetime tied to some context object not specified here
struct Wrapper<'a> {
    // storing it as a reference to use Rust's ref checks
    // and avoid null-ref checks on each access
    obj: &'a c_object,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn from_ptr(ptr: *const c_object) -> Self {
        Wrapper {
            // Asserting that the pointer is not null just once
            obj: ptr.as_ref().unwrap(),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Wrapper<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // How to call free_obj() here?
        // I need to pass a double-ref to set my ptr to NULL
        // Essentially after this drop Wrapper instance content is undefined?
    }
}


Wrapper should probably store &'a ContextObject or PhantomData<&'a ()>, and *const c_object. Pointers can be cast without null checks to references.

@drewtato Wrapper does a lot of field access.  I do not want to constantly do (*self.obj).field everywhere.  The self.obj.field is far more ergonomic, and shows that it is Rust-ensured to be non-NULL

nah, @drewtato is pointing you in the right direction, ergonomics come secondary to correctness - both for the way 'a is used and that you should keep it as a pointer. A Deref implementation or helper method can help with ergonomics.

Could you clarify why &'a obj is less correct than *obj as a struct field, if the null check has already been done?  Note that *obj can be set to null at any point (by accident), but changing &obj requires unsafe code to do that.

The issue I see with a reference is that they must always be valid. That would be a problem in your Drop implementation since you'd call free_obj leaving obj either dangling or null (depending how you do it) which would be invalid. It would only be invalid for a slim timeframe, but still invalid and not allowed (I'm pretty sure).

The other problem is that 'a is the incorrect lifetime. The reference's life is tied to Wrapper and not the context object you mention. So if it were to leak outside the Wrapper, the borrow checker could see it as valid even when Wrapper is dropped. This is technically not invalid as long as you never use it for the lifetime beyond Wrapper, but its still better design not to create potential footguns.

@kmdreko thx for in depth replies! Are you saying that ref should not be used simply because it has limited safety guarantees, why pointer guarantees nothing, and hence better?  I was hopping to get some value out of the borrow checker. Also, I was reading about #[maybe_dangling] debate (unsettled) - seems related.

Hmm, I see an RFC for a MaybeDangling wrapper which sounds theoretically useful, but its not even implemented experimentally yet. And its not clear if that would be ergonomically better over a pointer.

One could make the field ManuallyDrop<&'a c_object> and use ManuallyDrop::take to semantically "move" the reference out from the field within the drop handler.

A safe and idiomatic way to implement wrappers for C libs has been introduced at https://github.com/ProgrammingRust/examples/tree/master/libgit2-rs-safe. The method is explained in their book.

There are a couple of architectural decisions in your code that I would change:

Wrapper should not have a lifetime. It owns its value, and doesn't depend on anything external. This should be obvious when thinking about the fact that its destructor destroys everything it depends on, nothing external has to be 'given back'. Be aware that lifetimes don't keep anything alive, they are just a way for the compiler to track dependencies. And Wrapper doesn't depend on anything, everything it contains is owned by itself.
Wrapper::from_ptr absolutely needs to be unsafe, as there's no sound way of implementing it without making unsafe assumptions. Read this for more information about soundness.
Do not use a reference. Like 'a, a reference is for storing a dependency to something owned, and we are the owner ourselves. Instead, us a raw pointer directly. Your situation is exactly what raw pointers are for.

All of that said, here's some code that demonstrates how working code would look like:
// Code generated by bindgen, from a C header file
#[repr(C)]
pub struct c_object {
    // some fields
    x: core::ffi::c_uint,
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn allocate_obj() -> *const c_object;
    pub fn free_obj(obj: *mut *const c_object); // double-ref to set my ptr to NULL
}

// Dummy implementation for demo purposes
pub mod dummy_c_impls {
    use super::c_object;

    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn allocate_obj() -> *const c_object {
        let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(c_object { x: 42 }));
        println!("Allocate {:?}", ptr);
        ptr
    }
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn free_obj(obj: *mut *const c_object) {
        if let Some(obj) = unsafe { obj.as_mut() } {
            let mut ptr = std::ptr::null();
            std::mem::swap(obj, &mut ptr);

            if !ptr.is_null() {
                println!("Free {:?}", ptr);
                unsafe {
                    std::mem::drop(Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut c_object));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Define Wrapper in a mod to prevent other objects from modifying ptr
mod wrapper {
    use super::{c_object, free_obj};

    // Safe Rust wrapper I need to design
    // lifetime tied to some context object not specified here
    pub struct Wrapper {
        // storing it as a reference to use Rust's ref checks
        // and avoid null-ref checks on each access
        ptr: *const c_object,
    }

    impl Wrapper {
        // Absolutely needs unsafe here, as there's not way of
        // implementing this function without unsafe assumptions
        pub unsafe fn from_ptr(ptr: *const c_object) -> Self {
            Self { ptr }
        }
    }

    impl Drop for Wrapper {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            unsafe {
                free_obj(&mut self.ptr);
            }
        }
    }

    impl core::ops::Deref for Wrapper {
        type Target = c_object;

        fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
            unsafe { self.ptr.as_ref() }.unwrap()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use wrapper::Wrapper;

    let value = unsafe { Wrapper::from_ptr(allocate_obj()) };
    println!("{}", value.x);
}

Allocate 0x2681b09aef0
42
Free 0x2681b09aef0


NonNull should be used instead of *const.

@trueequalsfalse Why? NonNull is not const, is it really better to cast away constness just for the null check?

Thanks!!! There is one problem:  My code is a plugin to C program, getting callbacks, and I am creating safe wrapper for other users to write safe Rust plugins. On callback from C, sometimes user creates new WrapperObj(c_object), and sometimes need to destroy them.  On each callback, my wrapper code must restore WrapperObj from a *void, and pass it to the user, plus on "cleanup" callback my wrapper needs to destroy them.  P.S. See https://github.com/gquintard/varnish-rs/blob/6acfdcd90250d739bce7b918c7821957e616ff4e/src/vcl/vpriv.rs

I updated my question: c_object has a user_obj: *void field, which I use to store Rust-allocated T. So when my FFI layer gets a new T from Rust code, it allocates c_object via C call, stores T as a *void in it, and passes control back to C code. Later, it gets back a pointer to c_object, and gives &T or &mut T to the Rust code, until at some point it needs to drop T and free up the c_object itself.

If it's Rust allocated, why store it in a void*?

Either way, I did answer your original question and I currently don't really have time to adapt it. I'd prefer if you asked a second question if you have follow-up questions. Stackoverflow isn't really meant as an interactive discussion platform; that's rather what Reddit or the Rust forum is for.
